# Hosting local Dojo for Django server

Tags: javascript, django, dojo

This question was probably asked before, but I am not able to find a good answer. I am using `Django` and want to host a local DOJO instead of using CDN .

I have a copy of dojo located in /share/dojo-release-1.11.2.  That folder has subfolders - `dijit`  `dojo`  `dojox`  `themes`

Should I use `dojoConfig = {..}` ? if so , what is the syntax for it ?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to use    `dojoConfig` , before loading `dojo.js` script

by example in the html file (adding `claro` css theme and append `class="claro"` to `body` )

```
<script>
    var dojoConfig = {
        //parseOnLoad: true, //if you want to parse without using parser.parse() set the value to true otherwise to false
        async: true
    };
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static %}share/dojo-release-1.11.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static %}share/dojo-release-1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
    require([
        "dojo/parser",
        "dijit/form/Button"
    ], function(parser,Button) {
        parser.parse();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">
        test Button
    </div>
</body>
```

PS : note the `{{ STATIC_URL }}` depends on how you load the dojo inside your django server , so you have to make it as your config .
myapp 
i'm not familar with django but i'llgive you this example :

you have an app called `myapp` : 
inside `myapp` you have to add some instructions inside `myapp/settings.py` to access static files ,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

then in your html template you load the files as follow :

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" href="{% static 'share/dojo-release-1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js' %}">
...
```

so the structure in your app should look like :

```
mysite
  ├── templates
  ├── static
  |     └─── share
  |            └─── dojo-release-1.11.2
  |                   └─── ... 
  ├──...
  .
  .
  .
  └──setting.py
```

That's all.

Comment: Thanks bRIMOs.  I am kind of stretching my knowledge on Django too. Would you be kind enough to elaborate a bit on  
>>note the {{ STATIC_URL }} depends on how you load the dojo inside you

So, how should I load it inside django server, supposing I have an app named myapp in django.

Comment: @developerdeveloper kindly , see my answer .

Comment: @developerdeveloper does it help ?

Comment: Indeed . Thanks Much !

Comment: Great :) , please up and mark the answer as resolved left top the answer ( like in this image => [image resolve post](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T8umg.png) )  Thank you